# Linker errors from Xcode 9.2 Objective-C with WCSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit

I am adding a watch capability to an existing fairly complex Objective-C iOS application (that I have inherited), but am getting an unexpected build error right from the start.

> ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/mac/Documents/raceQs-iOS/ios/raceqs_pod/Library'
>   ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/mac/Documents/raceQs-iOS/ios/raceqs_pod/Pods/build/Release-iphoneos'
>   ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/mac/Documents/raceQs-iOS/ios/raceqs_pod/Pods/build/Debug-iphoneos'
>   Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>    "_OBJC_CLASS_$_WCSession", referenced from:
>        objc-class-ref in MainClass.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

The error is generated when I add the following code to my Main class:

```
#import <WatchConnectivity/WatchConnectivity.h>
@interface MainClass ()<WCSessionDelegate>
@end
```

and

```
if ([WCSession isSupported]){
//     WCSession *session = [WCSession defaultSession];
  //      session.delegate = self;
  //      [session activateSession];

    }
```

I have researched the issue, and I think it's a problem with my build settings Library Search Paths which are:
[image: Library Search Paths]

Any suggestions would be gratefully received.

Comment: try with remove google analytics ios sdk because in watch google maps and all other google sdk not supported

Answer (score 0):

Fixed

Added WatchConnectivity.framework to Build Settings/Link Binary With Libraries